# Dynamically Create Arrows between Circles (D3)

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have a d3 (v7) visualization where I have a variable number of circles being drawn on the screen depending on my data set.

How can I get arrows connecting these circles? I'm trying to follow this guide: https://observablehq.com/@harrylove/draw-an-arrow-between-circles-with-d3-links

However, this is only for a set number of circles (2) and I will have a variable number of them depending on my dataset.

Below is my current d3 code that draws circles:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 800)
  .attr("height", 200);

var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodeObjs)
  .enter()
  .append("circle");

circles
  .attr("cx", function (d, i) {return i * 100 + 30})
  .attr("cy", 60)
  .attr("r", 30)
  .style("fill", "steelblue");
```

Comment: What version of D3 are you using?

Comment: @AlfonsoIrarrázaval 7.0.0

Answer (score 1):

To make the [observable example](https://observablehq.com/@harrylove/draw-an-arrow-between-circles-with-d3-links) dynamic there are a few factors to take into account:

- you need 2 link functions; 1 for horizontal and 1 for vertical - below I have `linkH` and `linkV` instead of just `link`
- the link function doesn't need to be called immediately so lose the `({ source: linkSource, target: linkTarget});` - you are going to need an array of `links` instead
- some choice between `linkH` and `linkV` - you can test if the x-gap is greater than the y-gap between two circles and choose a horizontal link; and vice versa
- in the example I've made the horizontal vs vertical decision in the link creation; then call `linkH` or `linkV` in the `.attr("d", ...)` section
- in the case that the arrow runs right to left or top to bottom you need to reverse the sign on the adjustment of the link `x` and `y`

See the working example below:

```js
const svgWidth = 480;
const svgHeight = 180;
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

// Define the arrowhead marker variables
const markerBoxWidth = 8;
const markerBoxHeight = 8;
const refX = markerBoxWidth / 2;
const refY = markerBoxHeight / 2;
const markerWidth = markerBoxWidth / 2;
const markerHeight = markerBoxHeight / 2;
const arrowPoints = [[0, 0], [0, 8], [8, 4]];

// Add the arrowhead marker definition to the svg element
svg
  .append("defs")
  .append("marker")
  .attr("id", "arrow")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, markerBoxWidth, markerBoxHeight])
  .attr("refX", refX)
  .attr("refY", refY)
  .attr("markerWidth", markerBoxWidth)
  .attr("markerHeight", markerBoxHeight)
  .attr("orient", "auto-start-reverse")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.line()(arrowPoints))
  .attr("stroke", "black");
  
// horizontal link 
const linkH = d3
  .linkHorizontal()
  .x(d => d.x)
  .y(d => d.y);

// vertical link
const linkV = d3
  .linkVertical()
  .x(d => d.x)
  .y(d => d.y);
  
// circle data
const n = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) * 2) + 2;
const circleRadius = 10;
const nodes = [];
const links = [];
for (let i=0; i<n; i++) {
  nodes.push({
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * (svgWidth - 20)) + 20,
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * (svgHeight - 20)) + 20,
    r: circleRadius
  });  
}
for (let i=0; i<n; i+=2) {
  const xdelta = Math.abs(nodes[i + 1].x - nodes[i].x);
  const ydelta = Math.abs(nodes[i + 1].y - nodes[i].y);
  links.push({
    source: { x: nodes[i].x, y: nodes[i].y },
    target: { x: nodes[i + 1].x, y: nodes[i + 1].y },
    arrowDirection: ydelta >= xdelta ? "V" : "H"
  });
}

const circles = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node");
  
circles
  .attr("cx", (d, i) => d.x)
  .attr("cy", (d, i) => d.y)
  .attr("r", d => d.r);
  
const arrows = svg.selectAll(".arrow")
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "arrow");
  
arrows
  .attr("d", (d, i) => {
    let reversed;
    if (d.arrowDirection === "H") {
      reversed = d.source.x < d.target.x ? 1 : -1;
      d.source.x += circleRadius * reversed;
      d.target.x -= (circleRadius + markerWidth) * reversed;
      return linkH(d);
    } else {
      reversed = d.source.y > d.target.y ? 1 : -1;
      d.source.y -= circleRadius * reversed;
      d.target.y += (circleRadius + markerWidth) * reversed;
      return linkV(d);
    }
  })
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
```

```css
.node {
  fill: green;
  stroke: steelblue;
}

.arrow {
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```